# sed: change the linebreak before a specific patern to a space

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to use sed to change a line breaks preceding a specific character and replace it with a simple space:

Example:

```
<link rel="colorSchemeMapping
"
href="marinedrugs-790193-original.fld/colorschememapping.xml">
```

Should be:

```
<link rel="colorSchemeMapping" href="marinedrugs-790193-original.fld/colorschememapping.xml">
```

I'm aware of the

```
':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

but am willing to add the double quotes as being mandatory preceding the line break.

Comment: `sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n(")\n|\n/\1 /g' file`?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! I am trying to run this in a shell script and is somehow not working. I will try to figure it out...

Comment: Do you want to update files inline? `sed -i -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n(")\n|\n/\1 /g' file`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'm trying this way `sed -i -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n(")\n|\n/\1 /g' "$1"` and nothing happens, I'm missing something... Is there a way not tu use -E?

Comment: If you cannot use `-E`, try with `-r`. You need a GNU `sed`

Comment: I am using the GNU sed on mac. -r does the same.

Comment: Try `sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\("\)\n\|\n/\1 /g' "$1"`

Comment: So weird. This for example works perfectly well for another sed `sed -i 's@content=\([^"][^ >]*\)@content="\1"@' "$1"`, however, the example you gave me is simply doing nothing for some reason :(

Comment: Try `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"\n/" /g; s/\n/ /g'` or `sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's/\n"\n/" /g' -e 's/\n/ /g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, nope.

Comment: may be you have dos style line endings? does `cat -v file` show `^M` at end of lines?

Comment: @Sundeep, correct, I can see those ^M at end of lines

Comment: See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Then you need `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n"\r\n/" /g; s/\r\n/ /g'` or `sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's/\r\n"\r\n/" /g' -e 's/\r\n/ /g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest replacing `newline+"+newline` with the `"` and space, and any other `newline` with a space:

```
sed -i -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n(")\n|\n/\1 /g' file
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"\n/" /g; s/\n/ /g' file
```

or

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's/\n"\n/" /g' -e 's/\n/ /g' file > newfile
```

**LINE ENDING NOTE**: If your endings are CRLF, you need to replace `\n` with `\r\n` in the above patterns.

Note `-E` will enable POSIX ERE syntax (to avoid using too many backslashes in the pattern).  The regex means

- `\n(")\n` - a newline, then `"` is captured into Group 1 and then a newline
- `|` - or
- `\n` - a newline.

The replacement is Group 1 value (`"` if it was matched) and a space.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/7QlpPK):

```
s='<link rel="colorSchemeMapping
"
href="marinedrugs-790193-original.fld/colorschememapping.xml">'
sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n(")\n|\n/\1 /g' <<< "$s"
# => <link rel="colorSchemeMapping" href="marinedrugs-790193-original.fld/colorschememapping.xml">
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, I was managed to make this working by using: `sed -i -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/(")\n/\1 /g' "$1"`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using GNU sed anyway:

```
$ sed -z 's/\n"\n/" /g' file
<link rel="colorSchemeMapping" href="marinedrugs-790193-original.fld/colorschememapping.xml">
```

If you find yourself using constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed then you're using the wrong tool and should instead be using awk or similar. All other sed constructs became obsolete 40+ years ago when awk was invented.